# Rails logging from controller upload method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I am very new to Rails, and I can't understand how can I log something from a particular controller method. I implemented a simple file upload, with `fileutils`:

```
    def file_upload
        require 'fileutils'
        require 'rest_client'
        tmp = params[:file_upload][:my_file].tempfile

        logger.info 'log information with logger'
        puts 'log information with puts'
        p 'log information with p'

        file = File.join("public", params[:file_upload][:my_file].original_filename)
        FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file

        RestClient.post 'http://externalapi', :destination => 'address', :subject => 'subject', :file => file, :api_key => 'apikey'


    end
```

but from within this method the logging doesn't works. However it does within any other method. I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4

Comment: So does logging work for all your other controller methods? How about other methods inside this particular controller? If this is the case, then perhaps this method isn't being invoked at all?

Comment: If I move the method inside another controller the controller does works. The method is invoked since I can see the file uploaded in the /tmp/ folder

Comment: So...the logging works if you move this method to a completely different controller? Is there anything else particular about this controller? By process of elimination, if this method actually works. And if it logs from within another controller, than it must be the controller itself that is problematic.